# Time Machine don't update/add/delete any files after initial backup

Tags: backup, time-machine, big-sur

my TM is configured since March 2020 and I thought everything works fince since last week where I wanted to restore a changed file and noticed that every backup is exactly the same like the one from November 2020. So I started investigating and it seems that TM don't get the info from the OS that files have changed because after the initial Backup where everthing is OK no files get updated/added/deleted.

**Big Sur 11.4**

To reproduce I did:

1. Format a new external drive
2. Run TM
3. Add some files to /Users/me/*
4. Wait for next TM backup

Things I already tried:

- Create new Spotlight index
- Delete .fsevents
- Delete com.apple.timemachine.plist
- Check excluded lists

TimeMachineMechanic Log:

```
2021-06-21 08:39:02.195715+0200 Finished copying from volume "Macintosh HD - Daten"
               1 Total Items Added (l: Zero KB p: Zero KB)
              22 Total Items Propagated (shallow) (l: Zero KB p: Zero KB)
         2109418 Total Items Propagated (recursive) (l: 148,17 GB p: 127,92 GB)
         2109419 Total Items in Backup (l: 148,17 GB p: 127,92 GB)
               1 Directories Copied (l: Zero KB p: Zero KB)
              16 Directories Move Skipped (l: Zero KB p: Zero KB) | 2109412 items propagated (l: 148,17 GB p: 127,92 GB)
               6 Files Move Skipped (l: Zero KB p: Zero KB) | 6 items propagated (l: 1,8 MB p: 1,8 MB)
2021-06-21 08:39:06.280725+0200 Backup result: {
    BackupStrategy = 2;
    BlocksToCopy = 0;
    BytesToCopy = 0;
    FreeBytes = 126486085632;
    PaddedBytesRequired = 439726198;
    Percent = 0;
    "_raw_Percent" = 0;
    "_raw_totalBytes" = 1;
    bytes = 0;
    "com.apple.backupd.SnapshotTotalBytesCopied" = 0;
    files = 1;
    totalBytes = 1;
    totalFiles = 2;
}

Analysis from 2021-06-21 07:40:00 +0200 to 2021-06-21 08:40:00 +0200 for 1 hours:
Backing up to WD (/dev/disk3s1,e): /Volumes/WD
Current free space on backup volumes:
✅   /Volumes/WD = 873,24 GB
No auto backups started in the period, last backup completed successfully 0.9 minutes ago,
last manual backup started 1.1 minutes ago,
Created 2 new backups, and deleted 56 old backups,
Created 2 new snapshots, and deleted 1 old snapshots,
cancelled 1 backups.
Of 2 volume backups:
    0 were full first backups,
    0 were deep scans,
    2 used FSEvents,
    0 used snapshot diffs,
    0 used consistency scans,
    0 used cached events.

Big Sur backup results:
Backup result: {
    BackupStrategy = 2;
    BlocksToCopy = 0;
    BytesToCopy = 0;
    FreeBytes = 126097203200;
    PaddedBytesRequired = 104857600;
    Percent = 0;
    "_raw_Percent" = 0;
    "_raw_totalBytes" = 1;
    bytes = 0;
    "com.apple.backupd.SnapshotTotalBytesCopied" = 0;
    files = 1;
    totalBytes = 1;
    totalFiles = 1;
}
Backup result: {
    BackupStrategy = 2;
    BlocksToCopy = 0;
    BytesToCopy = 0;
    FreeBytes = 126486085632;
    PaddedBytesRequired = 439726198;
    Percent = 0;
    "_raw_Percent" = 0;
    "_raw_totalBytes" = 1;
    bytes = 0;
    "com.apple.backupd.SnapshotTotalBytesCopied" = 0;
    files = 1;
    totalBytes = 1;
    totalFiles = 2;
}
✅ No error messages found.
```

For me it looks like TM doesn't get any info about the changes in the filesystem.
For safety I already switched to SuperDuper! but I really would like to get TM running properly.

Maybe someone has an Idea to get this fixed without reinstalling the OS.

Thanks a lot, Kornel